# Silverlight Application Navigation to a fragment requires the Frame to have content currently

Tags: silverlight-4.0

One of our users has recently reported the following error popping up on our production Silverlight application:

"Navigation to a fragment requires the Frame to have content currently"

I've Googled it but there doesn't seem to be too much information regarding the error.  Does anyone know exactly what this error means?

Comment: Further investigations show us that this appears to be an issue when users navigate to our app from saved links in their browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this happens when you first set the content of the frame to null as the following:

```
        this.ContentFrame.Content = null;
        this.ContentFrame.Navigate(uri);
```

Comment: but how do you work around it? how do you reset the frame so that you can navigate fresh?